# How can we update our excel file data by CodedUI?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am finding the solution to update my excel file data by c#.

I am doing like one method where I am importing some item through automation script and that item has autogenerated Uniq ID in an application.

I have one excel file in my local machine. That excel file having a column as ItemID. I want to update that ItemID value with recently generated ItemID,  so without update it manually and then I can use that updated file in my next script where for some more import function of the application.

Comment: Is this a CSV spreadsheet or a xlsx?

Comment: there are also a great  number of c# and excel examples - what specifically have you got stuck on

Comment: @Joe it is xlsx file .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# export to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486278/c-sharp-export-to-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Coded ui **does not support** Office Client application:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx